# Finding the 'function' that last altered a place in a register?

Tags: assembly, x86, ida

sorry I'm a complete noob when it comes to ASM and IDA. My programming experience is mainly as a Java Developer and I feel somewhat out of my comfort zone.

I'm doing a little reverse engineering and I managed to find pretty much what I wanted. I found the following condition in my program:

```
mov     ecx, [esi+500h]
cmp     byte ptr [ecx+679h], 1
jnz     loc_7256AAD
```

As far as I understand, it moves the value at [esi+500h] into register ecx, afterwhich it compares the byte at address [exc+679h] with the byte 1. If the result isn't 0 it jumps to the function loc_7256AAD.

My problem is that the byte at [ecx+679h] is effectively a boolean, always a 0 or a 1. This is fine, but I have no clue how to find the function that decides whether the result is a 0 or a 1. Basically I would just appreciate some advice on how to go about finding the place where [ecx+679h]'s value is set. Thanks.

I'll provide some code from the routine that calls this snippet incase it helps.

```
push    ecx
lea     eax, [esp+70h+arg_8]
mov     ecx, esp
mov     dword ptr [esp+70h+var_30], esp
push    eax
call    ds:mfc90u_280
mov     byte ptr [esp+70h+var_4], 9
mov     byte ptr [esp+70h+var_4], 1
mov     ecx, [esi+500h]
call    sub_7210050
mov     ebp, eax
test    ebp, ebp
jz      loc_7256E73
```

and loc_7256E73 is the first snippet.

Sorry if I rambled and I appreciate any advice, thanks.

After taking Jens advice, I tried to add a write trace breakpoint, but the memory location changes, i.e. the address ecx+679h is different each time. If anyone has anymore ideas it's greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `If the result isn't 0`: [JNE and JNZ](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html) are synonyms for the same opcode.  Not-equal is the right semantic interpretation in this case.  (ZF is set if `byte ptr [ecx+679h]` - `1` is zero, because cmp is like a sub that only sets flags).

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the program?

Then the easiest way should be to run it in a debugger; find the actual address and then making a write memory breakpoint at that address.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply Jens. Yeah I can run it in a debugger under IDA. So you mean, find the address of [ecx+679h], add a write memory breakpoint and afterwhich I should be able to see what function writes to it? Sorry, one other thing, what if the address turns out to be different each time the cmp     byte ptr [ecx+679h], 1 runs, then the write trace wouldn't work? Sorry for these amateur questions.

Comment: Yes, assuming ecx and the address doesn't change.

Comment: In that case, the routine that changes one of the flags might be the one that changes the other ones.

Comment: It does change, I just tried debugging. Thanks for the advice Jens, i'll try to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

A really cheap way is to abuse the uniqueness of the constants in your code snippet. `0x679` is a pretty unique struct offset, thus its very likely that any references to it in the applications module(s) refer to what you are interested in, in which cause you need only search for something along the lines of `mov [r32 + 0x679],r32` or `mov [r32 + 0x679],c32`.

Of course this method would need altering if the value is indirectly set, in which case you need to find something along the lines of `lea r32,[r32 + 0x679]` or `add r32,0x679`.

*r32 here stands for any 32-bit register, similarly c32 is any 32-bit (or less) constant, this is ollydbg notation, IDA should have similar wild-card searching*

Comment: I searched through for every reference to 679h it looks as if it is only ever used for cmp and never for mov/add/lea etc. Is this possibly because whilst 679h is a constant, ecx alters and thus at the time of the function being called/ran ecx has a different value? Sorry im terribly amateur at this.

Perhaps I should start to devise another way to find the required function. It's just frustrating because I feel 'so close'.

Comment: @user1104652: does the taken branch ever change? cause it might be possible that its never actually set, else, it might be set via another binary module, such as a loaded dll

Answer (score -1):

maybe because [ecx+679h] possibly points to a memory address that is used a lot, like the stack or the heap. so monitoring this is annoying since its a scratchpad for the application, for this situation, you might want to read the docs of your debugger if it supports if conditions for memory addresses changes,so you can set your debugger to only break into it whenever a write/read condition of specific value is met.

Comment: The OP said that `ecx` points to a different struct every time, not that there's a single high-traffic location.  The OP said that was the problem with trying to use a write watchpoint.  Good suggestion to try to filter the condition on writes of a specific value, but it won't help in this case.